# What listener should I use for a JTextField in a typing game?

Tags: java, events, listener, jtextfield

Here is my situation:
I am developing a java typing game, and I need to find the best listener for my JTextField.

```
JTextField typeBox;
```

The listener should be able to detect the user's input, send the text inside the box to the main game part for processing, and if the ending of a word is reached, the type box **MUST BE CLEARED** (so the user can type one word at a time, like in usual typing games).
I have tried KeyListener

```
    public class TypeBoxListener implements KeyListener
    {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            if (arg0.getKeyChar() == arg0.CHAR_UNDEFINED) return;
            String typedText = typeBox.getText();
            thisGUI.processUserInput(typedText);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        }   
    }
```

The problem of this is when the user reaches the ending of a word without RELEASING a key, and immediately type another key, that new key is lost.

I also tried DocumentListener

```
public class TypeBoxListener implements DocumentListener
{
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
        String typedText = paragraphPanel.typeBox.getText();
        thisGUI.processUserInput(typedText);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
        String typedText = paragraphPanel.typeBox.getText();
        thisGUI.processUserInput(typedText);
    }
}
```

This method is much more responsive than using keyReleased, however, I can't clear the text box using this method, because I'll get an IllegalStateException trying to modify the document inside a DocumentListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to define your textbox-clearing code as a `Runnable` and execute it via [`SwingUtilities.html.invokeLater`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) to get around the `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll try looking into your suggestion.